# Center header in menu control

Tags: wpf, menuitem, vertical-alignment

How do I vertically center a header in the menu control?

This was my try:

```
<MenuItem Header="File" StaysOpenOnClick="True" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" Click="Open_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

But its aligned to the Top-left.

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]

My whole menu now looks like this:

```
<Menu Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Name="menu1" Margin="0,0,0,384">
        <MenuItem Header="File" StaysOpenOnClick="True" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <MenuItem Click="Open_Click" IsEnabled="True">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Open" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

The header text 'file' still isn't vertically centered (which is what i want to center).
What exactly is this code centering? Is it the text 'open'?

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to format the header you'll need to explicitly layout the header control:

```
<MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <MenuItem Click="Open_Click" IsEnabled="True">
          <MenuItem.Header>
              <TextBlock Text="Open" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
          </MenuItem.Header>
      </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
```

**Update:**
To format the position of a MenuItem in the Menu you'll need to override the Menu's ItemsPanelTemplate. By default the Menu uses a vertical WrapPanel which justifies the items to the top. Replace the default with a panel of your choice (StackPanel, Grid, DockPanel, etc) and you'll be able center the menu items as you please. Here's an example:

```
<Menu Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Name="menu1" Margin="0,0,0,384">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="File" StaysOpenOnClick="True" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <MenuItem Header="Open" Click="Open_Click" IsEnabled="True"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Information gathered from [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3aaef3a1-85de-43f6-8fdf-25fbb3ff4591) on MSDN.

Comment: hi, i edited my original post. The header text of the menu isn't centered with this peace of code. Maybe you misunderstood me?

Comment: you're right, I did misunderstand you, but I've updated my answer with what I think you're looking for. Learned something new today, so thanks for the question!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to set the [`VerticalContentAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.verticalcontentalignment.aspx). If the aligmnet is still not to your liking there is probably a problem with the default `MenuItem` `Template`, it may not bind to the property or there are some margins or Paddings which shift the header.

Comment: Hi, I used that property too, and i didn't do anything with templates. Do you have an example with what you exactly mean by the template?

Comment: @Yustme: It's a property that defines what internal elements a control is made of and thus what looks like. See the [property docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) and this [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx).